# Is it possible to use the Paypal In-Context Checkout feature in place without success or cancel redirection?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I was reading today the Paypal Express Checkout w/ In-Context Checkout Docs and the feature looks promising in the scenario that you need to perform a purchase in place without page reload or redirection to another page, but the truth is that you still have to declare a returnurl and cancelurl in order to make it work.

Unless I am missing something, this takes the user to the same problem it tries to solve, leave the current page.  An undesired outcome for the real-time web-apps.  Is there a way to get some sort of call back without redirecting to another page? or this is not possible yet?

Comment: Well, `in-context` "solved" the need for a user the _leave_ a merchant _site_ - end user no longer is redirected to Paypal and back (to merchant site) - the entire flow occurs on merchant site. Hth..

Comment: Once the purchase is successful or cancelled, the user gets redirected to a success page or cancel page.  My question is about avoiding that, so once the purchase is complete, there is no (in-site) redirection to any other page that takes me away from the current page.